# Excel: refer to the fields in every row of a range passed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a couple of sets of periodical expenses and the times per year they happen, like this example:

```
12  € 422,88
12  € 423,60
12  € 1.576,80
1   € 33,84
4   € 30,00
12  € 852,00
```

Every record where the first column is 12 denotes a montly expense, a 1 means a yearly and a 4 a quarterly expense. Now I would like to make a monthly reservation for all the non-monthly expenses by adding every record's amount where the first column is not 12 and dividing the sum by 12.

I'm trying to do this by iterating over a range with both columns, like this:

```
Function Reserve(expenses As Range) as Currency
  Dim row As Range
  Dim total As Integer

  total = 0
  For Each row In expenses
    if row.Cells(0).Value2 != 12 Then Total += row.Cells(1).Value2
  Next row
  Reserve = total / 12
End Function
```

This problem is that the row.Cells(0).Value2 is not accepted. How do I refer to the two fields in every row of the range passed?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that in Ranges, by default the indices are 1-based, not 0-based as I originally assumed. Also, the not equal sign in VBA is <> and to increase a variable's amount, the += syntax is not supported.

The line should therefore be:

```
If row.Cells(1, 1).Value <> 12 Then total = total + row.Cells(1, 2).Value
```

Comment: The *main* problem was taking a very simple accounting calculation and resorting to VBA rather than doing a quick search to find out how to use Excel properly. The majority of issues new users encounter when learning to code typically involve reinventing the wheel from scratch when system designers have often created half a dozen out-of-the-box methods to solve their problem faster. That's the key learning point if you want to save time on future problems.

Comment: I admit that originally my question wasn't as clear as it is now, but I do feel that rather than answering my question, you kept telling me you'd prefer a different way to address the underlying problem. Whether that is using Excel 'properly', is subjective at best.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you resorting to VBA at all? An Excel formula would be far easier - or you can call the same Excel formula from VBA if required: `=(SUMIF(A1:A10,1,B1:B10)+SUMIF(A1:A10,4,B1:B10)*4)/12`

If I'm understanding you correctly, this takes the sum of the annual expenses, the sum of the quarterly expenses x4, then divides the subtotal by 12.

Comment: I need to function to be applied to various sets like the one in the example. They will have different numbers of rows. Is there a way for your example to not hard code the range?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do that - if you structure your data in a Table (Insert > Table) you can then just refer to the name of the column. So it would look more like **=(SUMIF(Table1[Period],1,Table1[Expense])+SUMIF(Table1[Period],4,Table1[Expense])*4)/12**. Or you could use something like **OFFSET(A2,COUNTA(A2:A1000),1)** to automatically count the length of your range, if there's nothing below it. You could build that OFFSET into a named range (Formulas > Name Manager). Or you could calculate the range dynamically in VBA and call the Excel formula on it from there.